# Certificate to prove that our program is virus-free?

Tags: c#, .net, security, antivirus, malware-detection

We are producing a software (C# / .NET 2.0), which is provided for download on a website.

Now this is a special program for only a few clients. As a consequence, many antivirus programs (Norton, Mc Afee, Avira, ... ) do not know our program and bring up a false alarm ("suspicious ...  " -  "not known by the community ... "etc.).

Many clients feel insecure, or do not know how to handle this.

So, how can this be handled in general? Can we add some sort of "certificate" that our program is guaranteed to be virus-free ?

Answer (score 1):

You can buy certificates for your executable:
For example from: https://www.symantec.com/products-solutions/families/?fid=code-signing

This should help.

Comment: Having a certificate doesn't mean that a piece of software is virus free. It just means it has been signed.

Comment: Yes, but it will help with false positives like he describes. Not in all cases like when the software behaves like a virus but with such "trust" warnings it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the certificate from a anti-virus/anti-malware vendor. It will routinely scan your website and provides a certificate to you which will help you build faith in customers,

https://www.mcafeesecure.com/pdf/mcafee-secure-for-websites-service-datasheet.pdf